# How to get all occurrences of duplicate records in a PySpark DataFrame based on specific columns?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, duplicates, multiple-columns

I need to find all occurrences of duplicate records in a PySpark DataFrame. Following is the sample dataset:

```
# Prepare Data
data = [("A", "A", 1), \
    ("A", "A", 2), \
    ("A", "A", 3), \
    ("A", "B", 4), \
    ("A", "B", 5), \
    ("A", "C", 6), \
    ("A", "D", 7), \
    ("A", "E", 8), \
  ]

# Create DataFrame
columns= ["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

When I try the following code:

```
primary_key = ['col_1', 'col_2']
duplicate_records = df.exceptAll(df.dropDuplicates(primary_key))
duplicate_records.show()
```

The output will be:

[image]

As you can see, I don't get all occurrences of duplicate records based on the Primary Key since one instance of duplicate records is present in "df.dropDuplicates(primary_key)". The 1st and the 4th records of the dataset must be in the output.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cant see 1st and the 4th records is dropduplicate keep one of each duplicates. see the code below:

```
primary_key = ['col_1', 'col_2']
df.dropDuplicates(primary_key).show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|    A|    1|
|    A|    B|    4|
|    A|    C|    6|
|    A|    D|    7|
|    A|    E|    8|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

For your task you can extract duplicated keys and join it with your main dataframe:

```
duplicated_keys = (
    df
    .groupby(primary_key)
    .count()
    .filter(F.col('count') > 1)
    .drop(F.col('count'))
)

(
    df
    .join(F.broadcast(duplicated_keys), primary_key)
).show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|count|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|    A|    1|    3|
|    A|    A|    2|    3|
|    A|    A|    3|    3|
|    A|    B|    4|    2|
|    A|    B|    5|    2|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason of using "F.broadcast". Seems that it works fine without using "F.broadcast".

Comment: It works fine without it. but it can have a huge impact on your performance. if one side of join is small its better to broadcast  that side. you can read the link below for more information:
https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-broadcast-variables/

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents

We can achieve this using Window function

1. Create dataframe:

   ```
    data = [("A", "A", 1), \
    ("A", "A", 2), \
    ("A", "A", 3), \
    ("A", "B", 4), \
    ("A", "B", 5), \
    ("A", "C", 6), \
    ("A", "D", 7), \
    ("A", "E", 8), \
    ]
    columns= ["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
    df.show(truncate=False)
   ```
2. Use the Window function on top of the primary key to evaluate the count and extract only those rows whose count is greater than 1 and then drop the count Column.

   ```
    primary_key = ['col_1', 'col_2']
    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(primary_key).orderBy(primary_key)

    df.withColumn('CountColumns',count('*').over(windowSpec)).filter('CountColumns>1').drop('CountColumns').show()
   ```

Please find the below image for reference:
[image]